# How can I put different lists in a list or tuple?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

I want to create a tuple or a list of each match (for example LB) with its data.

```
d ={'LB': {'team1': 'leuven', 'length': 27.0, 'team2': 'brussel', 'speed': 120}, 'HL': {'team1': 'hasselt', 'length': 60.0, 'team2': 'leuven', 'speed': 120}, 'LA': {'team1': 'leuven', 'length': 61.0, 'team2': 'antwerpen', 'speed': 120}, 'BL': {'team': 'brussel', 'length': 30.0, 'team2': 'leuven', 'speed': 120}, 'AH': {'team1': 'antwerpen', 'length': 78.0, 'team2': 'hasselt', 'speed': 120}, 'BO': {'team1': 'brussel', 'length': 110.0, 'team2': 'oostende', 'speed': 120}, 'AL': {'team1': 'antwerpen', 'length': 63.0, 'team2': 'leuven', 'speed': 120}, 'OA': {'team1': 'oostende', 'length': 120.0, 'team2': 'antwerpen', 'speed': 120}}
```

I already have this:

`for match, data in d.iteritems():`

```
strings = []
teams1= str(data['team1'])
lengths = str(data['length'])
teams2= str(data['team2'])
speeds = str(data['speed'])
strings.append (teams1)
strings.append(lengths)
strings.append(teams2)
strings.append (speeds)
strings.append (match)


print strings
['leuven', '27.0', 'brussel', '120', 'LB']
['hasselt', '60.0', 'leuven', '120', 'HL']
['leuven', '61.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'LA']
['brussel', '30.0', 'leuven', '120', 'BL']
['antwerpen', '78.0', 'hasselt', '120', 'AH']
['brussel', '110.0', 'oostende', '120', 'BO']
['antwerpen', '63.0', 'leuven', '120', 'AL']
['oostende', '120.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'OA']
```

How can I put each list in one big tuple or list like:

```
(['leuven', '27.0', 'brussel', '120', 'LB'],
['hasselt', '60.0', 'leuven', '120', 'HL'],
['leuven', '61.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'LA'],
['brussel', '30.0', 'leuven', '120', 'BL'],
['antwerpen', '78.0', 'hasselt', '120', 'AH'],
['brussel', '110.0', 'oostende', '120', 'BO'],
['antwerpen', '63.0', 'leuven', '120', 'AL'],
['oostende', '120.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'OA'])
```

or

```
[['leuven', '27.0', 'brussel', '120', 'LB'],
['hasselt', '60.0', 'leuven', '120', 'HL'],
['leuven', '61.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'LA'],
['brussel', '30.0', 'leuven', '120', 'BL'],
['antwerpen', '78.0', 'hasselt', '120', 'AH'],
['brussel', '110.0', 'oostende', '120', 'BO'],
['antwerpen', '63.0', 'leuven', '120', 'AL'],
['oostende', '120.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'OA']]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[[data[key] for key in 'team1 length team2 speed'.split()] + [match]
 for match, data in d.items()]
```

You need to fix that one `team` key to `team1`, though.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_list = []   
for match, data in d.iteritems():
    new_list.append([str(data['team1']), str(data['length']), str(data['team2']), str(data['speed']), match])

print new_list  
new_tuple = tuple(new_list)
print new_tuple
```

Comment: Than I get 8 times the first road, 7 times the second,... any idea how to fix it?

Comment: My output is just like this:   `[['leuven', '27.0', 'brussel', '120', 'LB'], ['hasselt', '60.0', 'leuven', '120', 'HL'], ['leuven', '61.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'LA'], ['brussel', '30.0', 'leuven', '120', 'BL'], ['antwerpen', '78.0', 'hasselt', '120', 'AH'], ['brussel', '110.0', 'oostende', '120', 'BO'], ['antwerpen', '63.0', 'leuven', '120', 'AL'], ['oostende', '120.0', 'antwerpen', '120', 'OA']]`   And then the tuple, so I think that's what you expected.   Are you sure that your code is only a declaration of `d` and then my code? Is indentation correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension:

```
result = [[data['team1'],data['length'],data['team2'],data['speed'],match] for match, data in d.items()]
```

What this does, is that for each `(match,data)` in `d.items()`, it will add `[data['team1'],data['length'],data['team2'],data['speed'],match]` to the list `result`.

Replace `d.items()` with `d.iteritems()` if you are using Python 2, but I recommend switching to Python 3.